# Incorrect storage of file in internal storage, Android

Tags: android

In developing android application, I am trying to save files in `internal storage` using a `generic method`. The code for the method is below:

```
    public String saveFile(String sourceFileAddress, String targetFileAddress, boolean shouldOverwrite){
        String returnMessage = null;

        if(new File(sourceFileAddress).exists()==false){
            return "Source file does not exists.";
        }

        File targetFile = new File(targetFileAddress);
        if(targetFile.exists()==false) {
            if(targetFile.getParentFile().exists()==false)
                targetFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            try {
                targetFile.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Failed to create new target file";
            }
        }else if(shouldOverwrite==false){
            return "Failed. \n File already exists.";
        }


        try {
            File source = new File(sourceFileAddress);
            FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(source);
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = fi.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                fo.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            fi.close();
            fo.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Failed to copy file. \n" + e.getMessage();
        }


        //test fields.. shows correct values first, but the subsequent return line gets hit again and the previously stored file is overwritten with a small size file(19 KB)
        boolean ifFileExistTest = targetFile.exists();
        long fileSizeTest = targetFile.length();


        return returnMessage;
}
```

When I place breakpoint in return line, it gets hit twice. In the first hit, the preceding test fields show correct file size, but in secod hit, it shows small file size. Why am I facing this problem?

Comment: The problem is somewhere else in the program. Make sure that you are calling the function only once.

Comment: Check the return value of mkdirs. And do NOT use .createNewFile(). The file will be created by the FileOutputStream.